# Знаки препинания.

Tags: пунктуация

**Идет ли дождь, или светит солнце — ему всё равно.**
Все ли знаки поставлены верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, все верно. Запятая перед *или* стоит, так как предложение сложное. Первый компонент (до тире) и последняя часть связаны бессоюзной связью, вторая часть имеет значение следствия.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, вместо тире должна быть запятая. Меня смущает союзная частица ЛИ. Нашла следующую информацию:
http://formaslov.ru
Толковый словарь русского языка онлайн >> ли
Ли... ли, союз повторяющийся - употр. в знач. разделительном или условно-уступительном. Рано ли, поздно ли, но случится. Дождь ли, снег ли, все равно придет. Ли... или, союз - то же, что ли... ли. Идет ли дождь, или светит солнце, ему все равно.

Comment: Соглачен, грамматически предложение оставляет желать.
Отсюда и все проблемы с пунктуацией.

Answer (score 0):

```
Идет ли дождь или светит солнце — ему всё равно.
```

Уверена, что это предложение **сложноподчинённое** с однородными придаточными **изъяснительными**, присоединяющимися  **ЛИ в роли подчинительного союза**. В придаточных предложениях заключён косвенный вопрос. Запятая между двумя придаточными, соединёнными одиночным сочинительным союзом ИЛИ, не ставится, ибо главное предложение "ему всё равно" для них общее. **Некрасивый, но формально правильный** вариант этого предложения выглядит примерно так: ***Идет ли дождь или светит [ли]солнце — ему всё равно.*** Вторая ЛИ успешно переместилась в ИЛИ.  От главной части задаём вопрос: ему всё равно (=безразлично) что? -  идет ли дождь или светит солнце. Тире здесь интонационное, можно поставить и запятую. Но тире лучше.
Ваше предложение должно выглядеть так: ***Идет ли дождь или светит солнце — ему всё равно. Или:  Идет ли дождь или светит солнце, ему всё равно.***

**Придаточные изъяснительные** могут служить для передачи косвенной речи. С помощью союзов что, как, будто, когда выражаются косвенные сообщения, с помощью союза чтобы — косвенные побуждения, ***с помощью союзных слов и союза-частицы ли —** косвенные вопросы.**(http://www.lingvotech.com/pridatochnie_izmyasnitelnie)

Здесь (http://formaslov.ru/%D0%BB%D0%B83) нашла следующую информацию:
***ли..., ли, ли..., или***
Присоединяет предложения или члены предложения, по значению исключающие или заменяющие друг друга, при указании на возможность или необходимость выбора между ними. В городе ли, в селе ли надо честно трудиться. Быстро ли, медленно ли, но работу надо делать. * ***Паду ли я, стрелой пронзённый, Иль мимо пролетит она (Пушкин). //***** Там же ***:Ли... или, союз - то же, что ли... ли. **Идет ли дождь, или светит солнце, ему все равно**.

Но*** с запятой перед ИЛИ в последнем примере я не согласна*** из-за общей для двух предложений конструкции "ему всё равно".